# Opening up the Java Console without a Internet Browser

Tags: java, unix, terminal, console

Thanks before anything.

I'm trying to debug a java application. It's the same that is included in this webpage here:

https://www.java.com/es/download/help/enable_console_linux.xml

or

http://linuxsysconfig.com/2013/12/how-to-enable-java-console-on-rpm-based-linux-systems/

But, I need to see the log or debug console on a unix terminal instead of in a graphic view.

Does someone know how to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the java program is a command line application inside a jar you would run the following in a terminal:

```
java -jar yourfile.jar
```

If it is an applet in a web page you could run:

```
appletviewer <url>
```

There are options for other kinds of java applications or other ways of distributing the program. The jar may need to know where other jar's are that it is dependent on. Generally, you would need to ask the author of that particular java program. There is a command-line debugger jdb, but IDE's like Netbeans, IntelliJ are much better.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to see the log from the applet in a unix terminal, do the next

the log of the applet you can find in the next path

/.java/deployment/log

there you can find the .log and the .trace files